# Loading pdf inside PDF.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I am trying to display a pdf inside an `iframe` using PDF.js. My pdf is not in my local directory, it is located in a NAS. Below is how I called my `iframe`.

```
<iframe id="framePDF" name="framePDF" src="http:127.0.0.1/web/viewer.html?file=#path-to-pdf#" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

At first I tried calling the file just by directly calling the files from the nest, as such `//100.100.0.10/folder/pdfname.pdf`. Using this will trigger a bad request error.

Then I tried to call it by adding the `http://` in front of the path file, hence `http://100.100.0.10/folder/pdfname.pdf`. But this doesn't show anything. The error that came out is ``unexpected server response (0) while retrieving pdf`.

I did my research, and NAS doesn't support the `http://` protocol. It uses either `smb://`, `cifs://`, or `file://`. Changing the `http://` to `file://` in calling the file will trigger the CORS policy.

So another idea is by using ColdFusion `cffile` to get the file as a binary pdf. Here is where I think it might work, but I just seem can't do it. I tried opening the file using `cfcontent`, but `cfcontent` just forces the pdf to be viewed using the browser built-in pdf viewer. I want it using my modified PDF.js viewer. So I use the `cfcontent` in another page, and link it to my `iframe`. The code will be something like this :

```
<iframe id="framePDF" name="framePDF" src="http:127.0.0.1/web/viewer.html?file=www.pdfviewer/pdf" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

This doesn't work as well. The viewer straight gone and doesn't even displayed on the screen.

Another idea that might work is by converting the pdf file. Since `cffile action="readbinary"` will output the pdf in it's binary form, I'm thinking of converting it back and link it to the `iframe`. However, I have no idea at all on how to do this. Based on other questions in this site, I can actually use javascript, but I have no idea how to start on this.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: You can't host the file off another file system like that. A filesystem doesn't use HTTP, and you can't link `file://` unless the main document was.

Comment: @Amy I can't link ``file:\\`` unless the document was? I don't understand

Comment: If the primary document was served with `http`, then the `file` protocol will not work.

Comment: @Amy, without the ``http``, the viewer.html won't even load. By using ``web/viewer.html?file=``, the iframe displayed a 404 error. That is why I put a ``http`` in front there

Comment: Yes, you use `http` when the resource uses the HTTP protocol.  Filesystems do not use HTTP.

Comment: Noted. Does that mean that there is no way for me to call both the viewer.html and pdf from the NAS?